# React native react sub array in object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am tired print out sub array data form an object in render()..

data object JSON:

```
{
"genres": [
    {
        "id": 27,
        "name": "aa"
    },
    {
        "id": 878,
        "name": "bb"
    },
    {
        "id": 28,
        "name": "cc"
    },
    {
        "id": 53,
        "name": "dd"
    }
], 
"status": "Released",
"tagline": ""
}
```

MyMainScreen.js

```
render() {
    return (
        <Container>
            <Content style={{marginLeft:0,marginRight:0}}>
                <InfoSection key={this.state.data.id} info={this.state.data}/>
            </Content>
        </Container>
    );}
```

InfoSection .js

```
const InfoSectionCard = ({ info }) => (
<View>
    <Text style={styles.cardGenreItem}>{info.genres}</Text>
</View>
);
export default InfoSectionCard;
```

I was using `.map` to solve this.. not it does work usually.
It works print out all JSON object when using`JSON.stringify(obj)`

When I try

`<Text style={styles.cardGenreItem}>{info.genres}</Text>`

the react error message are Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, name}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

But then add the '.map'

`info.genres.map(item =><Text style={styles.cardGenreItem}>{item.name}</Text>)`

the react error message are TypeError: undefined is not an object(evaluating 'info.genres.map')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear but am I right in thinking that the data shown in the json is parsed and stored in your component state? If you want InfoSection.js (should be .jsx) to display one Text component per element then you would want to do:

```
const InfoSectionCard = ({ info }) => (
    <View>
        {info.genres.map(genre => <Text style={styles.cardGenreItem} key={genre.id}>{genre.name}</Text>}
    </View>
);
```

export default InfoSectionCard;